# Configure SSL in jetty server using pfx file

Tags: java, ssl

I have a question about configuring SSL in jetty server.

I know we can use keystore and truststore to enable SSL in jetty server. But i have a **pfx** file. Can i use it directly instead of converting it into **keystore** and **truststore** jks files.

Reference code:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java

Answer (score 1):

PFX files are in fact PKCS12 key stores. So if you have an option to set the keystore type (I am not sure where in Jetty) you could use them directly.

See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL#Configuring_Jetty

you have to add the **keyStoreType** and **trustStoreType** set to **PKCS12**. I've used it inside the Karaf container that way (for some older version).

In the code you've linked I see no option for keystoreType (lite/embedded?), then you're bound to JKS store type and you have to convert the keystores

Comment: When i use pkcs12 with pfx file, i get caused by: java.security.invalidkeyexception: illegal key size exception. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Kumar if the keys are having length of 2048bit and more you need to have the JCE Unlimited Strength Policy installed

Comment: Yes, it is installed by default in JDK 1.7. Isn't it?

Comment: @Kumar  I've read OpenJDK 1.7+ should contain the Unlimited Strength JCE policy , but this exception really means unsupported key length

Comment: @Kumar javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(String transformation) should asnwer what's the limit. Please note only certain distributions of OpenJDK are including Unlimited JCE.